# To disable onfocus="this.blur();"

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

i am selecting values to my textbox from a popup window and i hav used
 onfocus="this.blur();" for textbox,  i want to disable this function in editbutton while i want to edit . i cant use readonly since the value is not passed to server due to postback,
pls help

Answer (score 4):

You mentioned that you cannot use `readonly` because it is not submitted back during a POST back.  Actually the `readonly` attribute, as in

```
<input ... readonly="readonly" />
```

is **submitted** back to the server during a POST.  The `disabled` attribute, as in

```
<input ... disabled="disabled" />
```

is **not submitted** backing durring a POST.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById("button").readOnly = true;
```

Comment: He wants the value sent back during a post back, disabled prevents this from happening.

Answer (score 0):

You can submit disabled controls by putting this line in the Page_Load:

```
Page.Form.SubmitDisabledControls = true;
```

for ASP.NET 2.0